# Remove transparency from a logo in a fading div

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I have a div that fades in images using javascript and a static image ontop of this div. I have the functionality bit working how I want it but I cant get it to look how I want it.

The logo, of type svg, that is on the div becomes somewhat transparent and the image in the div can be seen through the logo. I have tried messing around with the z-index and opacity of the elements but have had no luck.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="main-slider-container">
 <img src="img/logo.svg" class="img-responsive">
 <div class="slideme" id="slideme"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-slider-container{
  position:relative;
   background: blue;

}

#slideme div{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  z-index:0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #000000;

}

> img {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index:1;

}
```

Comment: Can you make any [example](http://jsfiddle.net) including the JS please?

Answer (score 0):

If it appears that you can see something *beneath* the logo, I'd *also* suggest you to set the background color.

```
> img {
    z-index:1;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SVG logo is transparent because it has a transparent background by default.

To change that just add a background color.

### Changed CSS

```
img {
  background-color: white;
}
```

### Full Example

I changed your img src to use a working SVG for clarity.

```css
.main-slider-container{
  position:relative;
  background: blue;
}

#slideme div{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  z-index:0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #000000;
}

> img {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index:1;
}

img {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-slider-container">
 <img src="http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_1Color_Black.svg" class="img-responsive">
 <div class="slideme" id="slideme"></div>
</div>
```

Also, when you were experimenting with z-index and opacity you may have not seen any effect because your CSS selectors `#slideme div` and `> img` are not selecting any of the given HTML elements.